# No result being displayed when running this query

Tags: php, mysql

I have to create a dynamic query based on the value received by the user's input, the value of the variables are posted by GET
When I simply run this

```
$qry = "SELECT* FROM LAPTOP WHERE 1=1";
$resul = mysqli_query($qry);
retrieve($resul);
```

all the content of this table are displayed without any error,(retrieve function here displays all the results based on the query) but when I try to modify it like this, I get a blank page

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM LAPTOP WHERE 1=1";
if(!empty($company))
{
$qry .= " AND company='$company'" ;
}
if(!empty($cpu))
{
$qry.= " AND cpu='$cpu' " ;

}
if(!empty($lifestyle))
{
$qry.= " AND lifestyle='$lifestyle' " ;

}
if(!empty($display))
{
$qry.= " AND display='$display'" ;

}
if(!empty($ram))
{
$qry.= " AND ram='$ram' " ;

}
if(!empty($HDD))
{
$qry.= " AND HDD='$HDD' " ;
}
echo $qry;
$result= mysqli_query($qry) || die(mysqli_error()) ;
retrieve($result) ;
$p = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ;
```

The result of `echo $qry;` is as expected, it displays this

```
SELECT * FROM LAPTOP WHERE 1=1 AND company='Asus' AND cpu='intel i3'
```

Is there a way to correct this? The reason I tried using WHERE 1=1 clause is that when all the variables are equal to NULL then the query returns all the rows from the table.

Comment: So you have `SELECT*` or `SELECT *` ... and, your query seems to fail for some reason. So incorrect table_name, column_name ... or the inputs "break" your SQL.

Comment: @djot I tried both SELECT* and SELECT * only because I wasn't sure about the syntax, I also tried breaking this in parts and it seems to work fine, I think there is some problem with the first WHERE clauase but I cannot figure other alternative out.

Comment: No, `WHERE 1=1 AND ...` is fine ... super smart ... I use it thousands of times in my project.

Comment: If you copy the query into mysql or phpmyadmin, do you get results?

Comment: @echo_Me: Well the function retrieve uses mysqli_fetch_assoc, I have called a function here because the results will be displayed as a dynamic html table, so nothing could fit in better than a function

Comment: What is `retrieve()` function? I don't know that?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the SQL. If you're not getting an error, the only explanation is that there's no matching data.

Comment: @djot `retrieve()` is his own function that displays the results of a query. He said it works when he uses the initial query with just `WHERE 1=1`.

Comment: try add this line and tell what error you got . `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: @Barmar there is matching data, this query does return value when entered manually, SELECT * FROM LAPTOP WHERE company=ASUS

Comment: That's not the same query as in your question, it's missing the cpu.

Comment: echo_Me there is no error.

Comment: then there is no data in your database with those conditions

Comment: @Barmar the query runs fine when cpu is set to intel i3.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you have no data in your database matched with your conditions . OR you have case sensitive with names.

example :

```
     cpu='Intel i3'   // with big I

     cpu='intel I3'   // with big I

     cpu='intel  i3'  // double space.
```

OR if you have big string , think to use `LIKE`

```
    $qry.= " AND cpu LIKE '%$cpu%' " ;
```

Comment: What exactly is the use of LIKE?

Comment: other suggestion is to see if you included the retrieve function.

Comment: learn here how LIKE works http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/like.php

Comment: retrieve is defined in the file a the query, I will check out the database and everything once again. Thank You for all the help you offered. :)

Comment: @CAO check the spelling of `Asus` with big A in your database also.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a typo also (`$resul_T_`)?

```
$resul = mysqli_query($qry);
retrieve($resul);
```

How you managed to lose that 't' and later get it back? ;)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out it may simply be that your query does not match any records.

Anyway what I usually do in a similar case is put all the conditions in an array, and then implode the array with 'AND'. That way you don't have to bother with 1=1 and it doesn't matter whether you have 0, 1 or more conditions.

```
<?php
$qry = "SELECT * FROM LAPTOP";

$conditions = array();

$cpu = 'Intel';
$ram = '24GB';

if(!empty($cpu))
{
    $conditions[] = "cpu='$cpu'";
}
if(!empty($lifestyle))
{
    $conditions[] = "lifestyle='$lifestyle'";
}
if(!empty($display))
{
    $conditions[] = "display='$display'";
}
if(!empty($ram))
{
    $conditions[] = "ram='$ram'";
}
if(!empty($HDD))
{
    $conditions[] = "HDD='$HDD'";
}

if( count( $conditions ) > 0 )
{
    $qry .= " WHERE ";
    $qry .= implode( " AND ", $conditions );
}

print_r($qry);
?>
```

Comment: Well then you should try it ;)